# Counting/grouping records in Access query

Tags: ms-access, count, filtering

I encountered an issue while trying to group records in a query.
What I need is - after I select DatePeriod from a comboBox - in an underlying subform to have a count of records for each employee within selected date period.

**Overview**

Note: for simplicity, I used two fields only.

Main Form has TabControl. Each Tab has a subform (Source: query). Each record in a query has Date (V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE) and Employee (V_WORKER) fields. Each `V_WORKER` has hundreds of entries (link to Oracle db).

On a form I have cboDatePeriod (example: „16.05.2018-15.06.2018“).
After selecting a value from a cboDatePeriod, a code compares DatePeriod with dates in a queries and filters it.

A query has INNER JOIN to qryEmployees, since I want to count records for specific Employees.

**Example of entries in a table DATA**:

```
|V_WORKER       | V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE  
| David Sylvian | 08.01.2018 14:38:21  
| David Sylvian | 08.01.2018 15:31:48  
| David Sylvian | 08.01.2018 16:22:07  
| Brian Eno     | 08.01.2018 17:33:07  
| Brian Eno     | 09.01.2018 16:18:50   
| Brian Eno     | 09.01.2018 17:09:21
```

**Code without date**:

```
SELECT qryDATA.V_WORKER,Count(qryDATA.V_WORKER) AS CountOfV_WORKER
FROM qryEmployeesCZS DATA ON qryEmployeesCZS.FullName = qryDATA.V_WORKER
GROUP BY qryDATA.V_WORKER
HAVING (((qryDATA.V_WORKER)<>""));
```

Query result example:

```
|V_WORKER       | CountOfV_WORKER              
| David Sylvian |  821   
| Brian Eno     |  92
```

It's how it should look alike, **after** applying DatePeriod filter. Let's move on.

**Code with date included:**
With Date included int function to remove Time stamp) instead having a single record for each Employee I have many records for each Employee, where each record is a count of records for a single day (grouped by V_WORKER and DAY).

```
SELECT qryDATA.V_WORKER, Int([qryDATA].[V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE]) AS V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE, 
Count(qryDATA.V_WORKER) AS CountOfV_WORKER
FROM DATA 
INNER JOIN qryEmployeesCZS ON qryDATA.V_WORKER = qryEmployeesCZS.[FullName]
GROUP BY qryDATA.V_WORKER,Int([DATA].[V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE])
HAVING (((qryDATA.V_WORKER)<>""));
```

Query result example (I used int function to remove timestamp):

```
|    V_WORKER    | V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE | CountOfV_WORKER   
| David Sylvian  |      08.01.2018       |        4   
| David Sylvian  |      09.01.2018       |        6   
| David Sylvian  |      10.01.2018       |        2   
| Brian Eno      |      11.01.2018       |        4   
| Brian Eno      |      12.01.2018       |        2   
| Brian Eno      |      15.01.2018       |        5   
| Brian Eno      |      16.01.2018       |        3
```

**What I want:**
After selecting Date period from a comboBox, I want to count a records grouped by V_WORKER - it should look like this:

```
|    V_WORKER-  | CountOfV_WORKER   
| David Sylvian |     26    
| Brian Eno     |     17
```

I tried with a Textbox in a subform which counts records, but of course it counts all records, not grouped by employee.

What I'm thinking of (in a moment of desperation) to have two queries in a subform: queryOne will have all records with dates and no grouping, and a second one (source: queryOne) with removed Date field and grouping included.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just count the EmployeeName field in addition to pulling it straight? I may be missing something without knowing your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how aggregation and GROUP BY work.

If you group by date, you will get the count per date.
If you want to only group by employee to get the full count, then do that. Remove `V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE` from the GROUP BY clause.

Which date would you want to get with the full count? The first? The last? Then use `MIN()` or `MAX()` aggregate functions for the date.

---

Edit from comment:

Then the date goes into the WHERE clause, like this:

```
SELECT qryEmployees.EmployeeName, Count(*) AS EmpCount
FROM (Data_Servisi INNER JOIN qryEmployees ON Data_Servisi.WORKER = qryEmployees.EmployeeName) INNER JOIN City ON qryEmployees.CityID = City.CityID
WHERE Data_Servisi.V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE BETWEEN Forms!myForm!DateStart AND Forms!myForm!DateEnd
GROUP BY qryEmployees.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Now I see I wrote my question in a hurry.
With CountOfWorker I get a count for each day, i.e. 8 entries on 1st of september, 5 in May the 2nd etc.
What I want is to count how many records are for each worker. In an example above, it would sum 8+5=13.
But this has to be done in my form, since I want to find out how many entries are within Date period, i.e. 1.9.2017-1.10.2017.
The problem is that if I sum records in a form (which are counted per day in a query), I get a sum of all records for all workers, instead grouped by worker. This can be done in a report, but I need it in a form.

Comment: Andre, If I group by WORKER I get an error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression  "V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE' as part of aggregate function.". If I add Count to V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE I'll get the count og all records. But I still need V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE information - if I add it, the result is again count by each date, not cumulative.

What I need is to group the data from a subform after aplying Date period filter.        
Just a note: formatting text doesn't work for me, don't know why. In edit mode it's formated, but when I save it, its gone.

Comment: @Vedran: Please **edit** your question to add more information, e.g. the current query you tried. Also please add sample data and expected result - I really don't understand what you want to achieve. See [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: Here is whyI need V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE:
Let's say there are 12 entries for each employee. Each for one month. On a form, in a comboBox, I select TimePeriod, i.e. January-February. After selecting Timeperiod, in a subform I'll have 2 entries per employee, and then I will count these records, for each employee.
Idea is to count how many records (entries) each technitian entered within selected time period.
That's why I need V_LOCATION_VISIT_DATE - to narrow number of records per each employee, and to count only records which are within selected DatePeriod. For aech employee.

Comment: As I wrote: *Then the date goes into the WHERE clause* , see Edit above @Vedran